# automatically get data from server storage then upload to database

Tags: php, mysql

i want to ask about how to automatically insert data into database every day for my website(based php and mysql)? the data source is from computer server storage. The scenario is like this: 
Everyday there will be different file with same format(it can be txt file or excel file) that are uploaded to my computer server. And i want to update my database automatically everyday  using that data.

Thank so much before

Comment: It would help if you posted a sample of your data and some of the code that's giving you trouble. :)

Answer (score 1):

If the server is Linux based you can use cron jobs. In the cron job you'll have to set to open the script once a day. This way the script will automatically upload the info in the database.
If the server is Windows based you can use Scheduled tasks. You'll have to make the scripta home page for a browser and in the Scheduled tasks you'll set it to open the browser once a day and this way you'll automate it. I'm not completely sure but this way you'll have to close manually the browser.

Answer (score 1):

cronjob is the best option for this kind of work.
in cronjob you can write your script for data insertion and set time as you need. suppose you set 24 hrs, then after each 24 hrs,this script is executed by cronjob and your data will be executed.
hope it make some sense. cronjob is a server option and if your server supports it,you can find it by it's name usually at the bottom.
Happy coding!